# error:cannot find symbol class connection

Tags: mysql, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;
class FirstProgram
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connection con = 
  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atul","root","password");
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from data");
while(rs.next())
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));
con.close(); 
}
 catch(Exception e)
 {

System.out.println(e);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connection` is no Class make it `Connection`

```
 Connection con = 
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atul","root","password");
```

Always remember the naming convention of `JAVA` .The Class names should always start with Capital letter not small letter.So according to this convention the jdk developers are not going to name the class as `connection`

Comment: @user2601676   You are using `connection con` make it in Upper case ie `Connection con`

Comment: @user2601676 Always remember the naming convention of `JAVA` .The Class names should always start with Capital letter not small letter

Answer (score 0):

Increase the scope of Connection variable because again you will face the problem when you will use connection variable in finally block(future).

That is before try block write this.

```
 Connection conn=null;
```

But in your code you have written connection which has c as small letter. That may be your problem.So make it to

```
 Connection instead of connection
```

because name of class is always starts with Capital letters coding standards and naming conventions of Java.

So your code become with addition of finally block.

```
import java.sql.*;
class FirstProgram
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Connection con=null;
        try
        {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atul","root","password");
         Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from data");
         while(rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally{
            con.close();
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Why the answer is downvoted??Please give reason before downvoting any answer.

Comment: shoaib i have done but show error is con already defined in main

Comment: Check the code and never close connection in try block because if you get exception in try block then con.close() will never be executed and your Connection object will remain open which is not good.

Comment: You need to learn why you got that error. You will face the same error in future may for small letter and may be for Scope problem.So learn dont just correct your code.